# How to call API in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api

I want to create a summary page for Covid-19 cases. I found this API : [CORONAVIRUS COVID19 API](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10808728/SzS8rjbc?version=latest#e831c268-9da1-4d86-8b5a-8d7f61910af8)

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/south-africa/status/confirmed/date/2020-03-21T13:13:30Z");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

My question is: how I can call/get the methods on this API using ASP.NET MVC?

And please note that I'm a beginner

Thanks

Comment: ...And do what with the data?

Comment: What do you mean by 'using' asp.net MVC? MVC is a framework for hosting websites and APIs. You can run any code you like within it, including calling out to other APIs, but MVC doesn't provide any specific support for this other than being able to run normal C#. The code you have here looks fine, so what's the problem you're experiencing with using it?

Answer (score 0):

This code would allow you to get the data from the Uri you provided above:

```
var c = new HttpClient();
var r = await c.GetAsync("https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/south-africa/status/confirmed/date/2020-03-21T13:13:30Z");
var json = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But if you can provide a tutorial on youtube or anywhere so I can understand the concept especially in ASP MVC